Run function when Stripe Checkout is successful JavaFx
I have a javafx project, and I have implemented Stripe as a payment gateway. So, I want to make an update if the payment succeeds, but without using a URL, which means without endpoint restful, because it takes time I think.
Is there any other method that allows me to execute a method update after payment?
package com.projet.projet.projett.Controllers;

import com.stripe.Stripe;
import com.stripe.model.checkout.Session;
import com.stripe.param.checkout.SessionCreateParams;

public class PaymentService {

    public String createCheckoutSession(Long amount) throws Exception {
        Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_51PosTgDdlayRiD5ZyUHUcNMQx29VRlCeqmGis0ptpAsYUagA39B648GS7u72L3tMmzpW7TV2kWTq1DIsKt5XxlfS0016EJl1VO"; // Replace with your Stripe Secret Key

        SessionCreateParams params = SessionCreateParams.builder()
            .addPaymentMethodType(SessionCreateParams.PaymentMethodType.CARD)
            .addLineItem(SessionCreateParams.LineItem.builder()
                .setPriceData(SessionCreateParams.LineItem.PriceData.builder()
                    .setCurrency("usd")
                    .setUnitAmount(amount)
                    .setProductData(SessionCreateParams.LineItem.PriceData.ProductData.builder()
                        .setName("Sample Product")
                        .build())
                    .build())
                .setQuantity(1L)
                .build())
            .setMode(SessionCreateParams.Mode.PAYMENT)
            .setSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8080/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}")
            .setCancelUrl("http://localhost:8080/cancel")
            
            .build();

        Session session = Session.create(params);
        return session.getUrl();
    }
}


Stripe seems to have lots of documentation about this https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders  and https://docs.stripe.com/checkout/fulfillment#trigger-fulfillment-on-landing-page , did you have specific questions about implementing those?
